# Passing dynamic functions from parent component to grandchild component Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, events, angular-material

I am creating a common table component for my angular application so that the component takes input for rows, columns, along with some action button handler functions and render table.

The table will be something like this
[image]

I
In this way, a single component can be used to render table for the whole application.

```
//parent-component.ts

parentFunction1(){
  //edit User
}
parentFunction2(){
  //delete User
}
parentFunction3(){
  //view user
}
```

I am passing data from the parent component as

```
//inside some-parent.component.html

<common-table
    [columns]="columnConfig"
    [dataSource]="rowConfig">
</common-table>
```

In my `common-table.component.html`, based on conditions I need to render different components as:

```
//inside common-table.component.html
<table-cell [row]="row" [column]="column"></table-cell>
```

from `table-cell.component.html` I need to call functions of `parent-component.ts`. For different components, my function name may vary, is there any way in angular so that if json

```
           [
              {
                name: 'Edit',
                type: 'button',
                outputHandler:parentFunction1
              },
              {
                name: 'Delete',
                type: 'button',
                outputHandler:parentFunction2
              },
              {
                name: 'View',
                type: 'button',
                outputHandler:parentFunction3
              }
            ]
```

like this can be passed from parent component and use the functions of the parent component from grandchild `table-cell.component.html`

I can use output and eventemitter, but as number of functions passed and name of functions may vary, so It cannot be hard corded. How to achieve this. Please help as I searched a lot but could not get the solution.

Comment: Are you planning to pass the function name as string in component configuration?

Comment: @VimalPatel No I dont want to pass function name as string, I want to pass whole function

Comment: that means as a function reference. Correct?

Comment: Yes, also I want that if I call that function from grand component it can access the properties of Parent component just in the same way as an event emitter does

Comment: Why you want to access the parent component properties from child? I guess you need to check your component design first. You are deviating from the basic component interaction.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, the functions are dynamic which I pass, I just want that when I call parentFunction1 from table-cell, It should able to access the properties written  parentcomponent

Comment: the function is in parent component so it will have access to all properties of that component.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226967/discussion-between-n3018-and-vimal-patel).

Answer (score 3):

This is how your root component looks like.

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = "CodeSandbox";

  myConfig: ConfigModel[] = [
    {
      name: "Edit",
      type: "button",
      outputHandler: this.parentFunction1
    },
    {
      name: "Delete",
      type: "button",
      outputHandler: this.parentFunction2
    },
    {
      name: "View",
      type: "button",
      outputHandler: this.parentFunction3
    }
  ];

  parentFunction1() {
    console.log("parent func 1");
  }

  parentFunction2() {
    console.log("parent func 2");
  }

  parentFunction3() {
    console.log("parent func 3");
  }
}
```

As you are passing this configuration to your grand child component. you can invoke the function directly from your configuration object.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of config">
  <button (click)="action(item)">{{item.name}}</button>
</div>


export class ActionComponent {
  @Input() config: ConfigModel[];

  action(item: ConfigModel) {
    console.log(item);
    item.outputHandler();
  }
}
```

[Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-function-in-child-h14vy?file=/src/app/app.component.ts)